# How to lock down a specific operating system in grub

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, password

I am currently dual-booting one of my laptops, but I want the Linux distro to be practically hidden completely. So far I have been able to make it so then you have to press Shift for the grub menu to show up, and I have encrypted my Linux root partition (I do not have a home partition). I've heard that you can assign a password to a specific operating system, but I'm a little bit confused about how to do it.

Can I make it so that Windows does not require logging in?

How do I make it so that only my Linux OS is password protected?

(Note: I am using Windows 10 with Zorin OS 15 Core)

Edit: I am not talking about the windows login, I'm meaning, can I have it so then grub doesn't require me to log in to access windows (in the grub menu), but I still need to login into grub to access Zorin. Also, the people I'm trying to prevent from getting into my Zorin root partition aren't particularly smart so I don't really care if they could just use a live USB or something to get into it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up a supervisor user and password will restrict any other user from using menu entries, editing menu entries and from using the grub console. Adding `--unrestricted` to a [`menuentry`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#menuentry) allows any user to use that menu entry without entering username / password and adding `--users` with a list of user names allows additional users to access a `menuentry`.

For a minimal setup you need to add a superuser with password and add `--unrestricted` to the `menuentry` in `/etc/grub.d/30_os_prober` that generates your Windows menu entries.

1. Edit `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`, find the `menuentry` responsible for the Windows entries and add `--unrestricted` to this menuentry. In my case I searched for the string `Windows` and edited the next `menuentry` line. The edited block now looks like this:

   ```
         cat << EOF
   menuentry '$(echo "${LONGNAME} $onstr" | grub_quote)' --unrestricted $CLASS --class os \$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-$(grub_get_device_id "${DEVICE}")' {
   EOF
   ```
2. Add your passwords to the end of `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`:

   ```
   cat << EOF
   set superusers="freddy"
   password freddy 1234
   EOF
   ```

   Note that it doesn't matter which config file in `/etc/grub.d/` we use for our passwords. We could also use `00_header` or `10_linux` instead.

   If you want to encrypt your password, run `grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2`, enter your password twice and use the generated string `grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.<a_very_long_string>` as your password. The password entry must then begin with `password_pbkdf2` instead of `password`:

   ```
   password_pbkdf2 freddy grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.68B90AFC[...]86858AF939
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   to update grub and check if your generated Windows entry in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` has the `--restricted` flag. The generated `30_os-prober`-block should look similar to this:

   ```
   ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
   menuentry 'Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)' --unrestricted --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-A25E43975E436361' {
       insmod part_msdos
       insmod ntfs
       set root='hd0,msdos1'
       if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  A25E43975E436361
       else
         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root A25E43975E436361
       fi
       parttool ${root} hidden-
       drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
       chainloader +1
   }
   set superusers="freddy"
   password freddy 1234
   ### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
   ```
4. Reboot and test.

Related links:

- [Authentication and authorisation in GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Authentication-and-authorisation-in-GRUB) (GRUB manual)
- [Grub2/Passwords](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords) (Ubuntu documentation with examples)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!